# Find month of first purchase in customer data

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a pivot table which shows the number of transactions per month per customer.

It is very messy to print, so here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can see for `customer_id` 1 (red), they first bought in August 2019 (green). This means the customer is 12 months old. I got the number 12 by counting backwards from the most recent month.

How can I extract this information programatically for all customers?

I would like to add an extra column called `tenure` which counts how old the customers are in months.

I guess I should try to count the number of columns backwards / forwards until I find the first non 'nan` number.

But I have no idea how to do that. I have tried some suggestions from similar questions here. Transposing the dataframe and using `Series.first_valid_index()` for each customer, or using a mix of `df.isnull()` and `idxmax()` but I couldn't make it work.

Any help appreciated. I'm sure it's an easy fix but I am lost.

My sample df:

```
df.to_dict()


{'customer_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
 'Jan 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Feb 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 1.0,
  9: nan},
 'Mar 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Apr 19': {0: nan,
  1: 1.0,
  2: 1.0,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'May 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: 1.0,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Jun 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Jul 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: 1.0,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: 2.0,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: 2.0},
 'Aug 19': {0: 1.0,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 1.0,
  9: nan},
 'Sep 19': {0: 2.0,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Oct 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: 1.0,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 1.0,
  9: nan},
 'Nov 19': {0: 1.0,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: 1.0,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Dec 19': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: 1.0,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Jan 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: 1.0,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Feb 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Mar 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Apr 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'May 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Jun 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Jul 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Aug 20': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: 1.0,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is convert columns to month periods in numbers and test first non missing value by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), added [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for avoid match forst column if only missing values row. Last subtract from right side vals value of index by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html):

```
df = df.set_index('customer_id')
df1 = df.notna()
df1.columns = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns, format='%b %y').to_period('m').astype('int')
s = df1.idxmax(axis=1).where(df1.any(axis=1))

df['tenure'] = s.rsub(df1.columns[-1])
```

---

```
print (df)
             Jan 19  Feb 19  Mar 19  Apr 19  May 19  Jun 19  Jul 19  Aug 19  \
customer_id                                                                   
1               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0   
2               NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
3               NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
4               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN   
5               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
6               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
7               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     2.0     NaN   
8               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
9               NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0   
10              NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN   

             Sep 19  Oct 19  Nov 19  Dec 19  Jan 20  Feb 20  Mar 20  Apr 20  \
customer_id                                                                   
1               2.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
2               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
3               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
4               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
5               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
6               NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
7               NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
8               NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
9               NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
10              NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   

             May 20  Jun 20  Jul 20  Aug 20  tenure  
customer_id                                          
1               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      12  
2               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      16  
3               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      16  
4               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      13  
5               NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0       0  
6               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      10  
7               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      15  
8               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       9  
9               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      18  
10              NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      13
```

Answer (score 1):

`d` is your dictionary from the question:

```
from itertools import count

df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('customer_id')
df['tenure'] = df.rename(columns=lambda x, c=count(len(df.columns)-1, -1): next(c)).idxmin(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             Jan 19  Feb 19  Mar 19  Apr 19  May 19  Jun 19  Jul 19  Aug 19  Sep 19  Oct 19  Nov 19  Dec 19  Jan 20  Feb 20  Mar 20  Apr 20  May 20  Jun 20  Jul 20  Aug 20  tenure
customer_id                                                                                                                                                                        
1               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     2.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      12
2               NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      16
3               NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      16
4               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      13
5               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0       0
6               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      10
7               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     2.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      15
8               NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       9
9               NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      18
10              NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      13
```